# How do I print multiple indexes from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Bit of a weird title, sorry. I have an array generated from [this](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query) PHP script which talks to game servers to pull information from them.

A friend told me I should be able to do it through a foreach loop, but I have been trying but not successful. Suck at PHP.

Here is the section of the code I'm stuck on.

```
try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    $info = $query->getInfo();

    foreach ($info $index => $1) {

        if ($index == 6 || $index == 7) {
            echo $1;
        }


    /*print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetRules( ) ); */
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
finally
{
    $Query->Disconnect( );
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP vars dont start with numbers !! $1 has no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your foreach syntax

Add as

```
  foreach ($info as $index => $i) {

    if ($index == 6 || $index == 7) {
        echo $i;
    }
```

Example: 
Suppose your array is like below

```
$game = [
  0 =>  'cricket',
  1 =>  'baseball',
  2 =>  'footbal'
];
```

Then you can get **index** and **value** like below.

```
foreach($game as $index => $value)
{
  echo "index is $index and game is $value";
}
```

It will print

```
index is 0 and game is cricket
index is 1 and game is baseball
index is 2 and game is football
```

Hope this will clear your basic foreach concepts

Comment: I get this with that. I think I tried this the first time. I'm really not good with this style PHP though to be honest.     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /var/www/html/web2/index.php on line 27

Comment: Hey, I'll admit I rarely do any coding. I chose specifically to do a research based dissertation but was told it now has to have a working protype application to go with it :(

Comment: you cannot start a variable definition in php starting with a number. you can read my example. it might clear your concepts

Comment: I am sorry @Ayaou. I didn't see this. I just added corrected the syntax. I have edited my answer

Comment: That worked. Cheers. Sorry for my lack of knowledge with something obviously so basic. Easier to try at first then ask here rather that looking and using outdated methods haha.

Comment: Quick addon, saving a question. What do I echo both of these as though they are one. So it'd print "Players: 7 / 50" or whatever. `echo "<h1>Players: ".$info['Players']."</h1>";
     echo "<h1>Max Players: ".$info['MaxPlayers']."<h1>";`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `$Query = new SourceQuery();` line somewhere?

If this line works

```
$Query->Connect(....);
```

Then this line wont

```
$info = $query->getInfo();
```

As the first line uses an object called `$Query` and the second line uses something called `$query` when it should be using the object called `$Query`.
Case in this case is very relevant.

Also `$info = $query->getInfo();` should be `$info = $Query->GetInfo();`

This line is also illegal and I would have thought it would throw an error message

```
foreach ($info $index => $1) {
```

It is missing the `as` syntax and `$1` is not legal as variables have to start with an alpha character

It should be something like

```
foreach ($info as $index => $value) {

    if ($index == 6 || $index == 7) {
        echo $value;
    }

} // you were also missing the closing bracket on your foreach loop
```

Comment: I mean, if I use print_r ($Query->GetInfo( ) ); it prints the array properly.